# Уведомление об ошибке авторизации и регистрации php laravel

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

У меня есть формы регистрации и авторизации. Они работают, за исключением вывода ошибок. Например при неудачной авторизации должно вывести на поле 'number' ошибку 'Авторизоваться не удалось'. Либо же при регистрации должно вывести на поле number 'Такой пользователь уже зарегистрирован'. При этом редирект работает, но сами ошибки не выводятся. То есть страничка просто обновляется. В чём может быть ошибка? Я новичок в php laravel и без понятия из-за чего это происходит
registration.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title-block')
    Регистрация
@endsection

@section('content')

    <div class="container">
        <h1 align="center">
            <a href="/"><img src="{{asset('images/logo.jpg')}}" alt="logo" class="home"></a>
            Register
        </h1>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="container" align="center">
        <form name="register" method="POST" action="{{route('user.registration')}}">
            @csrf
            <input class="text-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter your surname" name="surname" required>
            <input class="text-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" name="name" required><br>

            <input class="text-input-full-width" type="text" placeholder="Enter your number" name="number" required><br>

            <input class="text-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter your father`s name" name="fathers_name" required>
            <input class="text-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter parent number" name="parents_number" required><br>

            <input class="text-input-full-width" id="password" name="password" type="password" required placeholder="Enter password"><br>

            <label for="studies"id="RegistrationForm"><b>Choose your studies</b></label><br>
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic checkbox toggle button group">
                <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="btncheck1" autocomplete="off" name="btnstudies[]" value="Math">
                <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btncheck1">Math</label>

                <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="btncheck2" autocomplete="off" name="btnstudies[]" value="Language">
                <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btncheck2">Language</label>

                <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="btncheck3" autocomplete="off" name="btnstudies[]" value="Physics">
                <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btncheck3">Physics</label>

    </div>
            <br>
            <label for="classes"id="RegistrationForm"><b>Classes</b></label><br>

            <div class="btn-group-vertical" role="group">

                <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio1" autocomplete="off" checked value="2">
                <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio1">2nd class</label>

                <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio2" autocomplete="off" value="3">
                <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio2" >3rd class</label>

                <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio3" autocomplete="off" value="4">
                <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio3">4th class</label>

                <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio4" autocomplete="off" value="5">
                <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio4">5th class</label>

                <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio5" autocomplete="off" value="6">
                <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio5">6th class</label>

                <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio6" autocomplete="off" value="7">
                <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio6">7th class</label>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="final">
                <input type="checkbox" class="check-term" id="btncheck4" autocomplete="off" required>
                <label class="check-agree" for="btncheck4">I agree with a <a href="documents/term.txt">Terms</a></label><br>
                <button class="main-button" type="submit" name="sendMe" value="1" required>Register</button><br>
                <br><label class="check-agree" for="btncheck5">If you have already registrated, <a href="/login"> log in</a></label>
            </div>
            <hr>

    </form>
@endsection
```

RegisterController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
//    public function studies(Request $request){
//        dd($request->get('btnstudies'));
//        //you an store it in database now
//    }
    public function save(Request $request){
        if(Auth::check()){
            return redirect(route('user.private'));
        }

    $validateFields = $request->validate([

        'number' =>'required',
        'password' => 'required',

    ]);
        if(User::where('number',$request['number'])->exists()){
            return redirect(route('user.registration'))->withErrors([
                'number' => 'Такой пользователь уже зарегистрирован',



            ]);
        }
 $studies = implode(", ",$request['btnstudies'] );
    $user = User::create([

        'password' => $request['password'],
        'name' => $request['name'],
        'surname'=>$request['surname'],
        'number'=>$request['number'],
        'fathers_name'=>$request['fathers_name'],
        'parents_number'=>$request['parents_number'],
        'class' => $request['btnradio'],
        'studies' =>$studies
    ]);

    if($user){
        Auth::login($user);

        return redirect(route('user.private'));
    }

        return redirect(route('user.login'))->withErrors([
            'formError' => 'Произошла ошибка при сохранении пользователя'
        ]);
    }
}
```

login.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title-block')
    Log in
@endsection
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <h1 align="center">
            <a href="/"><img src="{{asset('images/logo.jpg')}}" alt="logo" class="home"></a>
            Log in
        </h1>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="container" align="center">
        <form name="sign" method="POST" action="{{route('user.login')}}">
        @csrf


            <input class="text-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter your number" name="number">
            <input class="text-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter your password" name="password">

            <button class="main-button" type="submit" name="sendMe" value="1" required>Log in</button><br>
            <br><label class="check-agree" for="btncheck5">Don't have an account? You can <a href="/registration"> register it right now</a></label>
    </form>
    </div>
    <hr>
@endsection
```

LoginController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request){
        $formFields = $request->only('number','password');
        if(Auth::attempt($formFields)){
            return redirect()->intended('/private');
        }
        return redirect(route('user.login'))->withErrors([
           'number' => 'Авторизоваться не удалось'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В шаблоне где ты хочеш вывести возвращаемую ошибку добавь код:

```
@error('number')
<div style="color: red;">
    {{ $message }}
</div>
@enderror
```